# Start-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Trigger Trigger XXX has an unexpected resource provider: , an unexpected resource type , or both

Tags: powershell, azure-data-factory

I have a trigger of type Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/triggers/BlobEventsTrigger

```
{
    "name": "FolderTrigger",
    "properties": {
        "annotations": [],
        "runtimeState": "Stopped",
        "pipelines": [
            {
                "pipelineReference": {
                    "referenceName": "FileTrigger Import Accounts Orders",
                    "type": "PipelineReference"
                },
                "parameters": {
                    "TriggerFolderPath": "@triggerBody().folderPath",
                    "TriggerFilePath": "@triggerBody().fileName"
                }
            }
        ],
        "type": "BlobEventsTrigger",
        "typeProperties": {
            "blobPathBeginsWith": "/triggers/blobs/orders/trigger",
            "blobPathEndsWith": ".json",
                 "scope": "/subscriptions/12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012/resourceGroups/europe-resource-integrations/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=deveuwintgr",
            "events": [
                "Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

When I am trying to start it (PowerShell IDE or CI/DI) as here:

```
$GetAllTriggers = Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Trigger -DataFactoryName $datafatoryName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup
$GetAllTriggers | ForEach-Object { Start-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -DataFactoryName $datafatoryName -Name $_.name -Force }
Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Trigger -DataFactoryName $datafatoryName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup
```

I am receiving the error:

Start-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Trigger : HTTP Status Code: BadRequest
Error Code: BadRequest
Error Message: Trigger FolderTrigger has an unexpected resource provider: , an unexpected resource type , or both.

I can start a trigger of type Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/triggers/ScheduleTrigger.

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error.
The problem with me was that I tried to start a trigger with no pipelines connected to it. I found this error by starting the trigger inside the portal and this doesn't seem to work.
by adding the following code around the start Trigger I check first if the trigger has any pipelines before actually starting the trigger.

```
 if ($triggers.properties.Pipelines){}
```

PS: triggers. comes from my foreach loop where I loop over every trigger as followed

```
$triggersADF = Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Trigger -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName


foreach ( $triggers in $triggersADF) {
```